# XSRF-TOKEN invalid response testing with mocha chai superTEST

Tags: express, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, supertest

**XSRF-TOKEN invalid response testing with mocha chai superTEST
**`

```
const app = require('../../../app.js');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
let request = require('supertest');
const { cookie } = require('express-validator');
var csrfToken;
var csrf;
agent = request(app);
describe('GET /api/csrf-token', () => {
    it('OK, Getting CSRF Token', (done) => {
      request(app).get('/api/csrf-token')
      .expect(200)
        .then((res) => {
          const body = res.body;
          csrf=res.headers['set-cookie'][0];
          csrfToken=body.csrfToken;
          expect(body).to.contain.property('csrfToken');
          done();
        })
        .catch((err) => done(err));
    });
  });

describe('POST /api/users/login', () => {
    it('OK, Logging in with super admin crediantials',  (done) => {
      request(app).post('/api/users/login')
        .set("Cookie",[csrf,`XSRF-TOKEN=${csrfToken}`])
        .set("XSRF-TOKEN",csrfToken)
        .send({"email":"super@abc.com","password":"abc"})
          .then((res) => {
            const body = res.body;
            console.log(body);
            expect(body.message).to.contain.property('Auth Successful');
            expect(body).to.contain.property('token');
            done();
          })
          .catch((err) => done(err));
      });
});
```

`

Login call getting token invalid while working fine on browsers and Postman

This is the code

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer actually am not setting cookies which is in response of get `XSRF-TOKEN` request